# Передача данных между Fragment-Activity-Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

**Есть Activity, DialogFragment, Fragment.**

В Activity есть два TextView, и метод который получает из них информацию и отправляет в DialogFragment через Bundle.

В Fragment есть таймер, который по окончанию времени должен оповестить об этом Activity, что бы она запустила метод сбора данных из TextView и выслала их в DialogFragment.

DialogFragment должен принять эти данные.

И в результате Fragment должен вывести на экран DialogFragment уже с информацией, которую получил от Activity.

Comment: Капитально переработайте вопрос. Адская мешанина из слабо согласованных, а местами некорректных предложений. Невозможно понять вложенный смысл

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, посмотрите сейчас, возможно лучше объяснил ситуацию

Comment: Одна из ошибок, что логика DialogFragment раскидана в Activity и в Fragment, тем самым создавая прочные связи. Он должен располагаться в одном месте, поэтому вам стоит переработать вашу архитектуру.

Comment: Что касается конкретного вопроса, то в Fragment можно спокойно сделать интерфейс обратного вызова Callback и Activity его реализовать. В итоге ваш Fragment будет дергать этот вызов и тем самым оповещать Activity: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: @AlexKrass могу я тогда в DialogFragment перенести метод сбора информации, и тогда просто в Fragment вызывать сам DialogFragment уже с информацией ?

Comment: @KzzxD надо смотреть на конкретную задачу, поскольку на примерном описании можно упустить важные детали и потом придется тратить силы на доработку. Просто подобные тесные связи компонентов являются как правило неправильными - фрагменты ничего не должны знать об активности, это она им должны давать информацию и вызывать, организовывать взаимодействие. Поэтому я бы переложил вызов DialogFragment на Activity, но лучше делайте так, как вам удобнее.

Comment: @AlexKrass но как я могу вызвать DialogFragment, в тот момент когда таймер в Fragment окончит отсчёт?

Comment: @KzzxD во так, как вам ниже и описали в ответе и как описано в приведенной мною ссылке - через событие обратного вызова.

Answer (score 2):

В Fragment делаем интерфейс слушателя окончания отсчета таймером

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    public interface OnTimeOutListener{
        void onTimeOut();
    }

    public OnTimeOutListener listener = null;
}
```

В активити реализуем интерфейс и передаем его нашему фрагменту

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment1.OnTimeOutListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...){
        Fragment1 f = Fragment1()
        f.listener = this
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeOut(){
        //читаем TextView и запускаем DialogFragment
    }
}
```

Внутри фрагмента в момент, когда таймер истекает, вызываем слушатель, если таковой имеется

```
if (listener != null)
   listener.onTimeOut()
```

С передачей текста в диалог, как я понял, проблем у вас нет

Comment: Хорошо сейчас попробую, и отпишусь