# Обмен данными между activity и fragments

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть активити с таймером, который увеличивает значение переменной Var. Есть 2 фрагмента. На активити отображается 1 из 2 фрагментов, их можно переключать.

Хочется сделать так, чтобы при смене фрагмента он бы брал актуальное значение переменной Var из активити. Необходимо иметь возможность изменять значение Var из фрагмента как для самого фрагмента, так и для активити.

Подскажите идею того, как это можно реализовать.

Сам смог реализовать лишь схему через интерфейсы и bundle, которая решает подобную задачу, но без таймера. Т.е. если фрагмент через bundle взял Var, а в активити она позже изменилась (из-за таймера), то фрагмент у меня не получает новое значение Var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979104/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-fragment-activity-fragment/979399#979399)

Вам будет лучше сделать в обратную сторону - во фрагментах реализовать слушатель событий таймера, а сам таймер хранить в активити

P.S. У меня снова возникло подозрение, что это задание в каком-нибудь вузе/спо, судя по количеству очень похожих вопросов за такой короткий промежуток времени. Я прав?)

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, я не догадался к таймеру привязаться. Когда попробую - обязательно отпишусь. Если не пойдёт, то с кодом. :d  И нет, я не студент, закончил уже. Так, для себя делаю.